# A questionable proof that $Z(S_n)$ is trivial for $n\ge 3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, symmetric-groups, least-common-multiple

I tried proving that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>2}$ the centre $Z(S_{n})$ of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ is trivial. I already have a proof, but I'm not actually sure whether it's correct. Would someone like to proofread it?

I tried proving it by looking at conjugation and order.
Let $\sigma \in Z(S_{n})$ and $\tau \in S_{n}$  be randomly given. Let $s$ be the order of $\sigma$, $s^{-1}$ the order of $\sigma^{-1}$ and $t$  the order of $\tau $.

We know that $\tau \in S_{n}$ , so $\sigma \cdot \tau \cdot \sigma^{-1} \in S_{n}$. We know that $\sigma$ commutes with everything, so $\sigma \cdot \tau \cdot \sigma^{-1} = \tau$ So $\tau$ and $\sigma \cdot \tau \cdot \sigma^{-1}$ both have order $t$.

We also know that $\sigma \cdot \tau \cdot \sigma^{-1}$ its order is $lcm(s, lcm(t, s^{-1}))$. But the least common multiple is both associative and commutative, so $\sigma \cdot \tau \cdot \sigma^{-1}$ its order is also $lcm(lcm(s,s^{-1}), t)$. But we know that $lcm(s,s^{-1}) = 1$, considering $\sigma \cdot \sigma^{-1} = id$. So therefore both $s$ and $s^{-1}$ must be equal to $1$, but that also means that $\sigma = id$. But then all elements in $Z(S_{n})$ must be the identity, which was what we wanted to proof.

My biggest problem with this proof is the part where I state that because the $lcm$ is commutative and associative, $lcm(s,s^{-1}) = 1$, is this like a legit move? I don't know why but this just rubs me the wrong way

Comment: If $s$ is the order of an element, that does not mean that $s^{-1}$ is the order of it's inverse!. Are you suggesting that if an element has order $4$, it's inverse has order $1/4$, whatever that means?
An element and it's inverse both always have the same order.

Comment: The order of $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are same.  Inverting the order as you have indicated in your proof doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jake Maybe I shouldn't have written it like that, but I do not mean that $s^{-1} = \frac{1}{s}$ or something like that, I simply mean that $s^{-1}$ is the order of $\sigma^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there are a number of problems with your "proof". First, $s^{-1}=s$ (and the notation is very regrettable), so your statement that $lcm(s,s^{-1})=1$ is not legitimate. However, the most serious mistake is that you have not used the fact that $n\geq 3$.

Try the following:

Suppose $\sigma\in Z(S_n)$ is not the identity. Then $\sigma(i)=j\neq i$ for some $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Now, since $n\geq 3$, there exists $k\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\backslash\{i,j\}$.

*Claim:* There exists $\tau\in S_n$ such that $\tau(j)=k$, but $\tau(i)=i$ (can you think of one?).

Given the claim, compute $\sigma\tau(i)$ and $\tau\sigma(i)$. Are they equal? If not, what can you conclude?

Comment: I like this proof. Thank you. Am I right in thinking that the claim can be proven by some form of induction on $n$? It seems trivial but I could be wrong.

Comment: Induction is not required. You just need to be able to pick 3 distinct letters in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Which means you need $n\geq3$

Comment: For the claim, we can just construct this $\tau$ right? Like for example $\{1,2,3\}$. We can define $\tau(1) = 3$ and $\tau(2) = 2$. So $(13)$, right?

Comment: If they are not equal, then we just constructed two "partial mapping" in $S_n$ for any $n \ge 3$ that doesn't commute with each other. As in, the rest of $\tau$ and $\sigma$'s map doesn't matter, as long as we have the mapping that you described, it won't commute. Is that correct

Comment: @Oran You actually need a map, not a partially defined one. The $\tau$ I was thinking of in my parenthetical question was $\tau=(j\,k)$.